# Android productFlavors key for different types

Tags: android, android-studio

i have define productFlavors in my build.gradle

```
productFlavors {   
   one {
           applicationId ‘ com.example ’  
          versionCode 1   
          versionName “ 1.1.0 ”  
          buildConfigField 'String', '**TYPE**', ‘ ” onestaging ” ’                }    


   two { applicationId ‘ com.example.two ’    
          versionCode 1   versionName “ 1.1.0 ”  
          buildConfigField 'String', '**TYPE**', ‘ ” twostaging ” ’  
       }  
   }
```

now i want for two flover 
 for twodebug **type** value should be **twostaging** and **tworelease** it should be **tworelease**

how i can do this ?